# How would I render a Choice field into a template in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

How would I render the choices to the below html like dropdown?

```py
gender_type = (('Male', 'Male'), ('Female', 'Female'), ('Transgender', 'Transgender'))
gender= models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=gender_type, blank=True)
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="" style="font-size: 13px; color: black; font-weight: bold;">Gender</label>
     <select type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Example input" name="genderDr">
         <option>Male</option>
         <option>Female</option>
         <option>Transgender</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It already seems to be in a dropdown. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I want to render choices field from model to my HTML template, doesn’t want hard coded choices in html

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried (i.e., your `views.py`)?

Comment: I’m using class base view ‘ListView’ and my model=PersonalInfo

Comment: I have tried this <div class="form-group">
  <label class="" style="font-size: 13px; color: black; font-weight: bold;">Gender</label>
     <select type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Example input" name="genderDr">
         <option>{% PersonalInfo.gender %}</option>
      </select>
</div> But nothing shows in dropdown..